# Looking to sort by first name and last name on excel

Tags: excel

I am looking to sort first name and last name into two different columns, they are currently in a cell in the following format "lastname, firstname". Is there a way to separate them because of the comma in between?

Thanks  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel 2013:

1. Make sure you have a blank column to the right of your column
2. Highlight your entire column
3. Click the 'Data' tab on the ribbon
4. Click 'Text to Columns'
5. Select 'Delimited'
6. Select 'Comma' or whatever your delimiter is
7. Click finish

Comment: Thanks! That was perfect